# Scrape a single link with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm scraping dior.com for its products. head/script gives me all the fields I need except for a product description. To scrape the description I need to follow the link (the url variable in the code below). The only way to do that I'm familiar with is by using BeautifulSoup. Can I parse it using only Scrapy? 
Thx guys.

```
class DiorSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'dior'
    allowed_domains = ['www.dior.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.dior.com/en_us/']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'^https?://www.dior.com/en_us/men/clothing/new-arrivals.*',)), callback='parse_file')
    )

    def parse_file(self, response):
        script_text = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'window.initialState')]").extract_first()
        blocks = extract_blocks(script_text)
        for block in blocks:
            sku = re.compile(r'("sku":)"[a-zA-Z0-9_]*"').finditer(block)
            url = re.compile(r'("productLink":{"uri":)"[^"]*').finditer(block)
            for item in zip(sku, url):
                scraped_info = {
                    'sku': item[0].group(0).split(':')[1].replace('"', ''),
                    'url': 'https://www.dior.com' + item[1].group(0).split(':')[2].replace('"', '')
                }

                yield scraped_info
```

Comment: Why not simply follow the url link and parse in another function? e.g.
`yield Request(scraped_info[url],callback=self.another_parse)`

Comment: You didn't ask this, but why in the world are you using a regex group on the JSON key and then doing string splitting rather than just letting the regex pull out the value you really want: `sku = re.compile(r'"sku":\s*"([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)"').finditer(block)` and then `item[0].group(1)` contains the sku without drama?

Comment: Separately, as the site is currently, you are only one small replacement away from being able to feed that text into `json.loads` and not have to use regex at all -- which is a by-far better outcome: `data = json.loads(re.replace(r"\s*window.initialState\s*=\s*", "", script_text))`

Comment: Thank you Matthew L Daniel. That script text contains all products on a page, and I want to split this big chunk into smaller blocks so that one block contains only one product. Then I iterate them gathering necessary fields, but there are fields the script text is missing, so I need to follow the url I've already defined to get to the product page and extract what is missing. Is my logic right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to extract additional information from a second request, instead of yielding the data there, you should yield a request for the URL that includes the information you already extracted in the [`Request.meta`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) attribute.

```py
from scrapy import Request

# …

    def parse_file(self, response):
        # …
        for block in blocks:
            # …
            for item in zip(sku, url):
                # …
                yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_additional_information, meta={'scraped_info': scraped_info}

    def parse_additional_information(self, response):
        scraped_info = response.meta['scraped_info']
        # extract the additional information, add it to scraped_info
        yield scraped_info
```